# Cannot see embeded youtube on react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, youtube

I am trying to add an embedded youtube video into my react-native-app the element is there on inspection but no content appears

```
<YouTube
            videoId="KVZPZI6W4"   // The YouTube video ID
            play={true}             // control playback of video with true/false
            fullscreen={true}       // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
            loop={true}             // control whether the video should loop when ended

            onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
            onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
            onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
            onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}

            style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
          />
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I tried using your video id in a youtube URL and it said the video was unavailable (might be private or any variety of reasons).

Try using the example video Id and see if that works:KVZ-P-ZI6W4
Also make sure you have a decent network connection.

```
<YouTube
  videoId="KVZ-P-ZI6W4"   // The YouTube video ID
  play={true}             // control playback of video with true/false
  fullscreen={true}       // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
  loop={true}             // control whether the video should loop when ended

  onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
  onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
  onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
  onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}

  style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
/>
```

Comment: Still just a blank space where the video should be